# How to migrate external procedure from Oracle Listener to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle-12c

Consider that I'm using C or java external procedure called from my Oracle 12.2 Listener (EXTPROC listener parameter).
That Oracle database will be migrated to Postgres.

My question is how to migrate the C or java external procedure?

Should I install C or java extension for Postgres, and then compile these procedures inside my Postgres database?

Comment: What does this procedure do? I have never heard of procedures called from the listener

Comment: That's procedures running in a different process so they cannot damage the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it as a normal C or PL/Java function in PostgreSQL.

If it is important for you to run the function in a separate process, give [PL/Container](https://github.com/greenplum-db/plcontainer/blob/master/README_PG.md) a try.